# Automatically rebuild dependencies in Qt Creator

Tags: qt, compilation, dependencies, qt-creator

Qt Creator (4.6.1) is driving me nuts. My application is split into 3 parts:

- the app
- the library
- a unit tests app

When I change a file within the library and rebuild the application, the compiler does not recompile the library but links with the old version of the library.

Also, when I change the library, recompile it and then compile the app, no compilation takes place because it uses the cached app.

Is there a setting to change that? Here's my project file:

```
TEMPLATE = subdirs

SUBDIRS += \
    app \
    lib_mylib \
    tests

app.depends = lib_mylib
tests.depends = lib_mylib
```

The lib is built as a static library:

```
TEMPLATE = lib
TARGET = mylib
CONFIG += staticlib
```

Comment: What operating system are you on? I often use structures like these on linux and never experienced such a problem

Comment: @Felix: Windows 7 and MSVC

Comment: Then it's possibly related to jom/nmake - you can try to disable jom in the build configuration, but this will significantly slow down the build

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I have used CONFIG += ordered, DEPENDPATH and PRE_TARGETDEPS to get rid of the same problems. It works for me on linux and on win with MSVC. Try it.

in your project pro file add:

```
CONFIG += ordered
```

P.S.: your lib should be listed first. Like :

```
SUBDIRS += \
    lib \
    app \
    tests
```

in your exe .pro file add this with correct paths:

```
DEPENDPATH += $$PWD/../lib
PRE_TARGETDEPS += $$OUT_PWD/../lib/liblib.a
```

More options and flags is to be found [here](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmake-variable-reference.html)

Comment: The `CONFIG += ordered` is not needed and does not change anything - it only slows down builds (It's basically the same thing with automatic dependencies based on the order). The `DEPENDPATH` and `PRE_TARGETDEPS` however should work.

Comment: `PRE_TARGETDEPS` was the key to make it work. Thank you! As far as I read, `DEPENDPATH` is not necessary anymore for Qt5.

Answer (score 9):

I know it's a little late, but I would like to give an a little more extensive answer why this happens and how exactly the other solutions help.

A working solution will be: You use either `b.depends += a` as you did before or `CONFIG += ordered` **and** add `PRE_TARGETDEPS += ...` to `b`. (Side note: ordered is not recommended, as it can drastically slow down your builds and is generally considered bad practice)

**TL;DR:** The reason why this special combination is needed: The `app.depends = lib_mylib` in the subdirs project ensure that the library is always built before building the app is started, and the `PRE_TARGETDEPS` ensures that the app is actually beeing rebuild everytime the library changed.

---

Long explanation:

To understand why that works, we need to understand how qmake handles subdirs. qmake is a Makefile generator, which means it will only create makefiles. So all dependency ordering must be done using the methods make prodives. To understand what happens, we must understand how make works, first.

In make, dependencies are relatively simple:

```
some_target: dep1 dep2 dep3
    some_command
```

means that if you want to create `some_target`, make will create `dep1`, `dep2` and `dep3` first, in an *unspecified order*. Once all 3 are finished, `some_command` is executed.

However, make will optimize this for files. Considering the following:

```
hello.txt:
    echo "creating hello"
    echo "hello" > hello.txt

hello2.txt: hello.txt
    echo "creating hello2"
    echo "hello2" > hello2.txt
```

Running make will create the both files and print both messages. Running it a second time will do nothing. The reason here is that make keeps tracks of already created files and file changes. Since `hello.txt` already exists, it is not created again. And since `hello.txt` has not changed, there is no need to create `hello2.txt` again. If you now externally change the contents of `hello.txt` and run make again, `hello2.txt` will be created anew and you will see the message.

Now with subdirs projects, this gets a little more complicated, as we now need dependencies between multiple different makefiles! This is typically resolved by recursive make calls. For your example, qmake creates the following code (simplified):

```
lib_mylib: FORCE
    $(MAKE) lib_mylib/Makefile

app: lib_mylib FORCE
    $(MAKE) app/Makefile
```

This code will, as expected, create `lib_mylib` first (blocking, i.e. the `lib_mylib` will only finish once the whole lib has been built) and after that create `app`. The `FORCE` depenency ensures that this command is always run, even if the target already exists.

---

With those basics in mind, we can now reconstruct what happens for qmake. Using the `b.depends += a` will generate code as above - it makes shure that all dependencies are built in the correct order, but nothing else! Using the ordered config will simply automatically create those depends rules, so there is no logical difference in how they work.

However, this is not enough to actually rebuild `app` when `lib_mylib` changes. It only ensures that `lib_mylib` is built before make starts building `app`.

In order to rebuild `app`, we use the `PRE_TARGETDEPS` - this adds a dependency as shown before to the make target in the apps makefile

```
app.exe: mylib.lib:
    #linker code
```

This means that every time `lib_mylib` changes, `app` is now rebuilt as well. Using this without the ordered config however can fail, as it is possible that make would first try to build `app` (which either does nothing, as lib has not changed, or will fail if lib does not already exists) and after that rebuild `lib_mylib`. Running make a second time will the rebuild `app` as well - but thats rather inconvenient.

So, thats why we need to combine those two. We need to control the order in which the different makefiles are executed and references the created artifacts from the other makefile - and thats exactly what those commands do.

Comment: "You use either b.depends += a as you did before or CONFIG += ordered and add PRE_TARGETDEPS += ... to b." I misread this ambiguous statement at first, I assume you meant you first add either (b.depends += a as you did before or CONFIG += ordered), then add PRE_TARGETDEPS += ... to b.

Answer (score 1):

Regardless the long and understandable explanation I've tried with

```
TEMPLATE = subdirs
CONFIG += ordered
SUBDIRS += \
    dynamiclib \
    staticlib \
    testlibs
```

for my rather small and short project and it worked for me.